# How do I provide error checking to ensure user input only allows letters and provides a looping error message if numbers are typed?

Tags: python

I am trying to provide a looping error message to the user for the customerName input so that the user receives an error message if they type anything other than letters aA - zZ,(I don't want to allow the user to input numbers specifically). I would like it to operate similar to the one I used for the customerAge input( which i provided as an example). but I cant seem to figure out the correct code to accomplish this. can anyone provide some insight?

```
customerName = input('Enter your name: ')

customerAge = int(input('Enter your age: '))
while customerAge <= 15 or customerAge >= 106:
    print('Invalid entry')
    customerAge = int(input('Enter your age: '))
```

Answer (score 2):

after reviewing all the answers I received (thanks goes out to all of you for the help). I coded it like this and it appears to be operating correctly.

```
customer_name = input('Please enter your name: ')
while not customer_name.isalpha():
    print('invalid Entry')
    customer_name = input('Please enter your name: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with what your program needs to do:

*Loop until the input is valid*

That will be it for all kinds of validation that are in the form of:

1) User inserts something

2) Something is wrong

3) Program informs user and asks for input again

So, in python:

```
valid = False
while not valid:
    valid = True
    customer_name = input('Enter your name: ')
    customer_age = int(input('Enter your age: '))
    if customer_age <= 15 or customer_age >= 106:
         print 'Enter a valid age'
         valid = False
    if not customer_name.isalpha():
        print 'Enter a valid name'
        valid = False
```

What we did here:

1) Set `valid` to `True`, so the happy case will let us out of the loop

2) Obtain both values

3) If any of them is invalid, set `valid` to `False` and inform the situation

You can even use 2 loops to validate separately.

**A note on the isalpha() method**: You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) and some good info about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667410/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-only-contains-letters-in-python)

*Also, as a bottom line advice:* never use camel case in python variables.

That notation is reserved for `Class` names. For variables, use lower case and `_`

Comment: " if customer_name == 'invalid name':  # This part is up to you" this is the part that throws my under the bus....im not sure what to put here to ensure that only letters are input and numbers are not allowed.

Comment: Edited with `isalpha()`

Comment: the rest of the code i think I grasp. but I am just a very beginning programmer taking my first class so I have only a limited understanding of the basics at this point, but I do thank you for your input, it was helpfull

Comment: customer_name = input('Please enter your name: ')
        while not customer_name.isalpha():
            print('invalid Entry')
            customer_name = input('Please enter your name: ')

Comment: Glad to hear it, feel free to accept the answer if it fits, or to answer your own question with the complete details of what was / solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Regex should do what you want

```
import re
while 1:
    name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
    if re.search(r'(?i)[^a-z]', name):
        print("Invalid name")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Why `while 1`? That looks like a bad practise.. just because `bool(1)` is `True`, you shouldn't use it anywhere

Comment: When sharing code on SO, I like to be as brief as possible to avoid detracting from the clarity of the core idea being demonstrated. It's my style preference.

Answer (score -1):

Check the `type` of each character with the `type()` function.

```
u_input = raw_input()
valid = ""
for char in u_input:
    if str(type(char)) == "<type 'int'>":
        valid = "False"
        break
    else:
        pass

if valid == 'False':
    print 'This string has a number! Gosh darn it!"
```

Place this in a function/`while` loop, and you have your looping error message. You can add other loops to ensure any other parameters.
This is the easiest, and likely the most efficient way.

More information on `type()` here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type

Comment: let's not recommend using type for a mundane task to a beginner

Comment: @Alvaro but `re` and `.isalpha()` is okay?

Comment: Of course, `isalpha` returns `True` if the string contains only letters (can it be any more on-the-point?) Using `type` for this wouldn't pass any serious review

Comment: @Alvaro didn't realize that. Duly noted. But this is one method. All the other ways were taken. If a more advanced Python coder comes across this, it may be useful.