# Validate user input using regular expressions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to be able to validate that the user has entered a valid name within my program.  If they have not entered a valid name i want the program to continue to prompt them to enter their name again.  If the name entered is valid i would like the program to greet the user.

So far i have:

```
import re

user_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
if not re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", user_name):
    print ("Error! Make sure you only use letters in your name")
else:
    print("Hello "+ user_name)
```

How would i loop this if their name is not valid??

Comment: If you don't want to allow an empty input, I would recommend using `^[A-Za-z]+$` instead of `^[A-Za-z]*$`.

Comment: Limiting your input to ASCII letters does users around the world a disservice.  If there are characters you truly can't handle, like spaces, blacklist them, but [let your users choose names that are meaningful to them](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names).

Comment: What are the rules for names that you are trying to enforce, can you enumerate them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user_name = '1'  #something that doesn't validate
while not re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", user_name):
    user_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    print ("Error! Make sure you only use letters in your name")
else:
    print("Hello! "+ user_name)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a `while True` loop only break out with `break` if you got a right answer:

```
while True:
    user_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    if not re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", user_name):
        print ("Error! Make sure you only use letters in your name")
    else:
        print("Hello "+ user_name)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

put everything in a while loop and have the condition your matching statement:

```
user_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
while not re.match("^[A-Za-z]*$", user_name):
    print ("Error! Make sure you only use letters in your name")
    user_name = input("Please enter your name: ")
print("Hello "+ user_name)
```

Edit:

using `str.isalpha()`

```
while not user_name.isalpha():
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you! I was thinking along those lines but was not sure if i could use not with while.  Are their other methods that can be used to validate users only enter letters?

Comment: you could use [`str.isalpha()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667410/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-only-contains-letters-in-python)