# How to not accept blank and space input for a frontend web registration form using python flask?

Tags: python, flask, frontend, flask-sqlalchemy, web-frontend

I have a code to create new f_name, l_name, email, id in my program, however it accepts any kind of input all variables. But, I want to limit the empty space/ whitespace to reject invalid input such as f_name, l_name, email, id

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881152/validate-user-input-using-regular-expressions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Validate user input using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33881152/validate-user-input-using-regular-expressions)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if string contains only whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405292/check-if-string-contains-only-whitespace)

Answer (score 0):

````
    if value is not None and hasattr(value, 'strip'):
        return value.strip()

    return value```
````