# Python Error message for entering a number instead of a letter

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling

I just started my programming education with python in school. One of the programs I started with simply asks you your name and then repeats it back to you. I'd like some help with getting an error message to show up if you put in a number rather than letters.

This is what I have:

```
    while True:
        name = input("What is your full name? ")
        try:
            n = str(name)
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter your name in letters, not", repr(name))
            continue
        else:
            break
    print(name)
```

Comment: You could provide what's you've tried - eg. inputs and outputs (or error) so that people can help you to spot the "errors" easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the name if only contains letters by using `string.isalpha()`
in your case you name it n so `n.isalpha()` will return True or False
for more information:

[How can I check if a string only contains letters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667410/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-only-contains-letters-in-python)