# Read a file .txt and write in a new .txt file only the rows that start with string values

Tags: python

I did a script to compare two files, count the elements and say how much times they appear. This information is saved in a new file. This last file, unfortunately, contains numbers and words. I need only the rows that starts with words in general (strings).

The initial code is this:

```
f1 = open("file1.txt", 'r')
f2 = open("file2.txt", 'r')




words1 = f1.read().split()
words2 = f2.read().split()
words = set(words1) & set(words2)


with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as output:
    for word in words:
        output.write('{} appears {} times in f1 and {} times in f2.\n'.format(word, words1.count(word), words2.count(word)))
```

The file out is made by this kind of text and I need only when starts with a word, e.g. `ACTION` for this lines:

```
ACTION appears 1 times in f1 and 1 times in f2.
1150.00 appears 3 times in f1 and 1 times in f2.
1.18233875e-05 appears 1 times in f1 and 1 times in f2.
2.52229049e-09-1.85248240e-13 appears 1 times in f1 and 1 times in f2.
8.85017800e-09-1.22652064e-12-1.37945792e+04 appears 1 times in f1 and 1 times in f2.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I check if a string only contains letters in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18667410/how-can-i-check-if-a-string-only-contains-letters-in-python)

Comment: How about 'words' like `'1tel'` or `'ready123'` - would you want to exclude anything that contains numbers, or only things that are numbers in their entirety?

Comment: Dear @Grismar thank you for your question. I would like to include also the ones like 1tel or ready123

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isalpha()` to check if something is a letter. Just check the first character of your string

```
f1 = open("file1.txt", 'r')
f2 = open("file2.txt", 'r')

words1 = f1.read().split()
words2 = f2.read().split()
words = set(words1) & set(words2)

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as output:
    for word in words:
        if(word[0].isalpha()):
            output.write('{} appears {} times in f1 and {} times in f2.\n'.format(word, words1.count(word), words2.count(word)))
```

Comment: Thank you @Bosco Hidalgo, very useful, it was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

User @boscohidalgo suggest checking if the text is all text with `isalpha`, but really, you want to know if the text is *not* numeric. After all, you want to include text like `'ready123'`, which returns `False` for `'ready123'.isalpha()`.

This would work:

```
if not word.isnumeric():
```

However, this doesn't catch something like `'-100'` or `1,000.00`. Since you probably want to exclude those, you may want to simply try and convert it to a floating point number and ignore it unless that fails:

```
try:
   float(word)
except:
   # do something
```

In your code:

```
with open("file1.txt", 'r') as f1, open("file2.txt", 'r') as f2:
    words1 = f1.read().split()
    words2 = f2.read().split()
    words = set(words1) & set(words2)

with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as output:
    for word in words:
        try:
            float(word)
        except:
            output.write(f'{word} appears {words1.count(word)} times in f1 and {words2.count(word)} times in f2.\n')
```

There's something to be said about the speed of various methods, if you need to consider that. This question goes into detail about alternatives for this simple approach: [How do I check if a string is a number (float)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354038/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-is-a-number-float)